# How to export txt to csv in a correct form with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, csv, text

I tried to convert to csv a text file, but it is wrinting in a very bad format. Here my part of txt :

```
8:40 AM LH1334  
Frankfurt (FRA)
Lufthansa   A320 (D-AIPP)   
Landed 8:40 AM
```

There isn't any ";" just space beetween them.
I get this when im using my code:

```js
A1 cell:    "8:40 AM LH1334 
A2 cell    " "Frankfurt (FRA)
A3 cell    " "Lufthansa A320 (D-AIPP) 
A4 cell    " Landed 8:40 AM
```

BUT I want to separate like this (A1 cell to A6, and after these 4 rows a new dataes start from B1 cell to B6) :

```
A1      A2      A3        A4                    A5              A6
8:40 AM LH1334  Frankfurt (FRA)Lufthansa    A320 (D-AIPP)   Landed 8:40 AM
```

How i have to fix my code?

```
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def to_2d(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

f = open('proba.txt', 'r')
x = f.read()

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=' ',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')

maindatatable = to_2d(x, 6)
print maindatatable
output.writerows(maindatatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what problem your are facing? (paste the current result VS the expected one OR error if it happens)

Comment: I get this : 
"8:40 AM LH1334 
" "Frankfurt (FRA)
" "Lufthansa A320 (D-AIPP) 
" Landed 8:40 AM

And i want to separate this to 6 columns like i wrote in the example in my question.

Comment: please add it to your question, people don't like to dig in comments :)

Comment: i added to my question!

Answer (score 1):

The separating character in your case is `newline`, e.g. `\r\n` or `\n`

You could use x = f.readlines() instead. This will return a list with the lines, each entry ending with a `newline` character. They can be removed by using .strip() method of a string, like

```
a = 'mystring\r\n'.strip()
```

So read the lines:

```
x = f.readlines()

# could use a list comprehension here
x_clean = [k.strip() for k in x]
```

and then join the entrys to a single string

```
y = ' '.join(x_clean)
```

If you want to use `csv.writer` the code is slightly different.

Comment: If i am using x=f.readlines() i get this : 8:40 AMLH1334 in the A1 cell, and i want to separate it to A1 cell = 8:40 AM;  A2 cell = LH1334

Comment: Then you need to handle this separately, use something like 'xyz 123'.split(' ') to split that entry to a list ['xyz', '123'] and append the entries it to the other list manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
with open('f.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(', '.join(lines))
```